# Get frequency for TS from and XTS for X12

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to automate some seasonal adjustment with the `x12` package. To do this I need a `ts` object. However, I do not need a simple `ts` object, but one whose start date and frequency has been set. For any given series I could type that, but I will be feeding a mix of monthly or weekly data in. I can get the data from a `quantmod` as an `xta` object, but can't seem to figure out how to extract the frequency from the `xts`.
Here is some sample code that works the the whole way through, but I would like to pull the frequency info from the `xts`, rather than explicitly set it:

```
getSymbols("WILACR3URN",src="FRED", from="2000-01-01") # get data as an XTS
lax <- WILACR3URN #shorten name
laxts <- ts(lax$WILACR3URN, start=c(2000,1), frequency=12) #explicitly it works
plot.ts(laxts)
x12out <- x12(laxts,x12path="c:\\x12arima\\x12a.exe",transform="auto", automdl=TRUE)
laxadj  <- as.ts(x12out$d11) # extract seasonally adjusted series
```

Any suggestions? Or is it not possible and I should determine/feed the frequency explicitly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested for this specific case, but try using `xts::periodicity` for the frequency:

```
freq <- switch(periodicity(lax)$scale,
  daily=365,
  weekly=52,
  monthly=12,
  quarterly=4,
  yearly=1)
```

And use the `year` and `mon` elements of `POSIXlt` objects to calculate the start year and month.

```
pltStart <- as.POSIXlt(start(lax))
Start <- c(pltStart$year+1900,pltStart$mon+1)
laxts <- ts(lax$WILACR3URN, start=Start, frequency=freq)
plot.ts(laxts)
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a champ. I spent forever looking for an attribute within `XTS` that gave the periodicity directly, I should have known there was a function to extract it from the data. Also thanks because I think I learned about 6 other things unpacking your code. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The xts::periodicity suggestion was helpful to me. I've also found the following approach using xts::convertIndex works well for monthly and quarterly data. It is untested for weekly data.

```
require("quantmod")
require("dplyr")
getSymbols("WILACR3URN",src="FRED", from="2000-01-01") # get data as an XTS
lax <- WILACR3URN #shorten name
laxts <- lax %>%
  convertIndex("yearmon") %>% # change index of xts object
  as.ts(start = start(.), end = end(.)) # convert to ts
plot.ts(laxts)
```